# Rectangle With Only One Border

Tags: wpf

I am creating a template for a button. How do I draw only the bottom border of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this make a rectangle of height 1 and vertically align it to bottom

```
<Rectangle Height="1" Stroke="Red" StrokeDashArray="1 2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Comment: This is a hack. Set BorderBrush="0,0,0,1"

Answer (score 21):

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
    <!-- Content -->
</Border>
```

You can set different thickness for any part of `Border` control.

Answer (score 6):

Since you want a dashed line, use a Line object and set it to the bottom of your control

```
    <Line Stroke="Red" Height="2" Stretch="Fill" X2="1" 
          StrokeDashArray="1 2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

If you don't need the Dashed line, I'd recommend a `Border` with the `BorderThickness` property set to `0,0,0,1`

Comment: The line does not, what I want, since it stretches also the DashArray. :( I guess, a custom decorator would be best.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want a [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), not a Rectangle in this case.

Comment: Can I make a dotted border effect with Border? I don't see aything like the StrokeDashArray property.

Comment: @LuisAguilar you should be able to set the BorderBrush property to any valid WPF Brush.  So yes, yes you can.  MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have a line at the bottom, you could just have a transparent Border which contains (at some point in the tree) a line.

Comment: Why transparent?  You could just set the BorderThickness to something like `.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0d, 0d, 0d, 1d)`.

Comment: Because a line is a bit more versatile drawing-wise than a border.

Comment: Even if that's true -- then why the Border at all?  And not just, say a grid, or some other element?  Does the border buy anything?  Or was it just a preference? -- Also: in what way is a line more versatile?  (aside from being able to go diagonal, etc.  as that's not really relevant here -- but I mean, it's got Stroke and StrokeThickness -- which are Brush and Double -- I'm not seeing a lot more versatility here.  What am I missing?)

Comment: With buttons, I tend to draw them in a border element. For simplicity I left out the content provider and whatnot. As for line versatility, I  keep elements in the tree aimed at future refinement.  I also stick to a lot of framework elements. They are lightweight and conceivably aimed at specific applications.  If I wanted to eventually animate the line for some buttons and not for others, it would be easy to do with a line, but not with a border. In the example above, I assumed the border was the top element. Animating the border moving back and forth would move child elements too, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use either:

- A Rectangle is a Shape (Geometry).
- A Border does not support a dashed line

Instead, I would create a custom [`Decorator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.aspx) (Border is a Decorator). You'll be able to customize it how you want and it contains a Child DependencyProperty, so you can wrap it around your content.